# MBR and data on pendrive

Tags: dd, mbr, data

I have a pendrive (`/dev/sdd`). I ran `fdisk -l` and that shows me the drive and its partitions.

After that I did:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=512 count=1
```

I deleted the MBR (so the partitions table) and now `fdisk -l` shows only the information about the disk (`/dev/sdd`) and not about partitions (`/dev/sddx`, `/dev/sddy`, ...)

However, when I put the pendrive into the computer, the system (Archlinux with XFCE) can read all the data in the drive.

My question is:

How does the system read all the data if all the information about partitions (e.g. where a partition start and end) is lost?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you formatted it directly without using partitions? Overwriting the first 512 bytes does not damage every filesystems, some deliberately leave the first sectors free.

You should check with `mount` which device was actually used for mounting and which settings were used specifically to mount it. If ArchLinux does some magic with offsets, you would be able to see it there.

Or maybe it used `GPT` partitions in which case they might be detected even if you overwrite the beginning of the drive, as `GPT` also has a backup at the end.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you erased the MBR, but you didn't erased the data itself. If you start reading just after the MBR you will be accessing the first partition and its data which is most probably what Archlinux is doing. Try the same command with a bs of 2048 and try to read the contents again. Anyway, for erasing data in a secure way you should use `shred`, there may be other tools for that job, but that is a good one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not tryng to erase data in a secure way (I usually use secure-delete suit). Anote question: why I have to use bs=2048? To erase more than just the MBR? Is it not enough to erase >512bytes such as bs=513?

Comment: You can find the answer to your question in the next link (in case of ext4 filesystems) https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout

Answer (score 1):

If that pendrive is partitioned with a GPT, erasing the first sector only removes the MBR and the **protective** DOS style partition table intended for non-GPT aware devices. Those will just throw an error with the protective DOS style partition table and report an unpartitioned device if that data is zeroed.

Linux however is aware of the GPT and ignores the protective DOS style partition table if a GPT is found. That's why your Linux box can still see the original partitions.